# How to link my comments to a post in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

All i must mention i am developing in Rails for the first time and trying to learn as i go. I used the direction from this blog to generate a post and comment scaffold. I have tweaked it a little to have relationship. But i am trying to link the comment to the post and i am not getting that results. I post but it not under the specific post.... please help

What i am trying to accomplish:

1. Allow a user to create a campaign (essentially a Title and a Description)
2. Allow User to have many Campaign
3. Allow user to have follower of the campaign (i have code for this)
4. Allow user to comment on the campaign .... So essentially the user must be logged in, is following a campaign and then can comment on the campaign

## routes rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    resources :commentonsqueals
    resources :squeals
    devise_for :users
    resources :users do
    get "users/show_image" => "users#show_image"
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
end
```

Users controller:

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
     has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb    => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
     validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type =>   /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


     has_many :comments

     has_many :Squealingcampaign,dependent: :destroy # 
     has_many :campaign,dependent: :destroy #
     has_many :followeds, through: :relationships
      has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent:   :destroy
     has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
     has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id"
     has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               class_name:  "Relationship",
                               dependent:   :destroy
     has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower


     has_many:avatar, dependent: :destroy
     has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy # remove a user's posts if his  account is deleted.
     has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
     has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy

     has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
     has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

## COMMENTS ON SQUEAL CONTROLLER

```
class CommentonsquealsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_commentonsqueal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /commentonsqueals
  # GET /commentonsqueals.json
  def index
      @commentonsqueals = Commentonsqueal.all
  end

  # GET /commentonsqueals/1
  # GET /commentonsqueals/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /commentonsqueals/new
  def new
      @commentonsqueal = Commentonsqueal.new
  end

 # GET /commentonsqueals/1/edit
 def edit

 end

 # POST /commentonsqueals
 # POST /commentonsqueals.json
 def create
     @commentonsqueal = Commentonsqueal.new(commentonsqueal_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @commentonsqueal.save
        format.html { redirect_to @commentonsqueal, notice: 'Commentonsqueal was     successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @commentonsqueal }
    else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @commentonsqueal.errors, status: : :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /commentonsqueals/1
# PATCH/PUT /commentonsqueals/1.json
def update
    respond_to do |format|
    if @commentonsqueal.update(commentonsqueal_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @commentonsqueal, notice: 'Commentonsqueal was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @commentonsqueal }
    else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @commentonsqueal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /commentonsqueals/1
# DELETE /commentonsqueals/1.json
  def destroy
    @commentonsqueal.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to commentonsqueals_url, notice: 'Commentonsqueal was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_commentonsqueal
      @commentonsqueal = Commentonsqueal.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def commentonsqueal_params
    params.require(:commentonsqueal).permit(:squeal_id, :body)
  end
end
```

## COMMENTS TO SQUEAL MODEL

```
class Commentonsqueal < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :post
end

<tbody>
<% @commentonsqueals.each do |commentonsqueal| %>
<tr>
<td><%= commentonsqueal.squeal_id %></td>
<td><%= commentonsqueal.body %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', commentonsqueal %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_commentonsqueal_path(commentonsqueal) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', commentonsqueal, method: :delete, data: {   confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

```
<%= link_to 'New Commentonsqueal', new_commentonsqueal_path %>
```

When i try to add comments it just dont attach or be under the post that i made

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution for displaying the post related to one another

```
def show
    @comments = Commentonsqueal.all.where("squeal_id = ?",
                    Squeal.find_by_id(params[:id]))
end
```